# UWP: Picker color pixel image

Tags: uwp

i work in uwp. i want to use mouse pointer to select season on an image and display ARBG color. Photos uploaded to UWP in Canvas. Here I found the color of the image in the file. Please help

```
private async Task<Color> GetColorFromPixel(string fileNameOfImage, int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)
        {
            var imageFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileNameOfImage); // Bild laden
            var imagestream = await imageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync(); // Bild in Stream umwandeln
            var imageDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imagestream.AsRandomAccessStream()); // Stream dekodieren
            var imagePixelData = await imageDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(); // Informationen über Pixel erhalten
            var bytes = imagePixelData.DetachPixelData(); // Pixel Daten bekommen
            var k = (yCoordinate * 1280 + xCoordinate) * 4;
            return Color.FromArgb(0, bytes[k], bytes[k + 1], bytes[k + 2]);
        }

        private void GetPhotoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            var colorFromPixel1 = Task.Run(async () => await GetColorFromPixel(@"Assets\D.png", 1219, 719)).Result;
            pixelBox.Text = "The color from pixel x1 and y1 is: " + colorFromPixel1;

        }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I want pointer mouse on picture display RBG color but can't?

Comment: I mean what is the problem what you are facing now? Getting the mouse position or getting the pixel data? The code looks like you've already done it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TappedRoutedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.tappedroutedeventargs?view=winrt-22621) to get the position of mouse on image.

Then you can use `GetColorFromPixel` to get color. But your image cannot be scaled, it must be 100% consistent.

**Page.xaml**

```
    <Canvas>
        <Image x:Name="testImage" Source="Assets/D.png" Tapped="{x:Bind Image_Tapped}" />    
    </Canvas>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var point = e.GetPosition(testImage);
    int xCoordinate = ((int)point.X);
    int yCoordinate = ((int)point.Y);

    var colorFromPixel1 = Task.Run(async () => await GetColorFromPixel(@"Assets\D.png", xCoordinate, yCoordinate)).Result;
    pixelBox.Text = "The color from pixel x1 is"+ xCoordinate.ToString()+" and y1 is" + yCoordinate.ToString()+": " + colorFromPixel1;
}
```